# How to make two requests inside one epic [redux-observable]?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm very new to rxjs and redux-observable. I'm trying to make two ajax requests inside one epic like so:

```js
import { mergeMap, filter, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';

export const doSomething = (action$: any, state$: any) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('SOMETHING_HAPPEND'),
    filter((action: any) => action.payload.status === 'SOME_ACTION'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON('/api/somewhere').pipe(
        map(() => push('some_route')),
        catchError((error: ResponseError) => of(statusChangeError(error)))
      )
    ),
    filter(() => {
      const { startTime, endTime } = getFormData(state$.value);
      return startTime && endTime;
    }),
    mergeMap(() =>
      ajax({
        url: './api/another',
        method: 'POST',
        body: getFormData(state$.value),
      }).pipe(
        map(() => push('another_route')),
        catchError((error: ResponseError) => of(statusChangeError(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

The first request must always run. The second request is conditional, I have `filter` for that.
I'm not sure if this is the proper way of doing such things. it seems to be working, except this part

```
map(() => push('some_route')),
```

in the first `mergeMap` is not getting called. The same part in the second `mergeMap` runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't be called if the request doesn't error.

Answer (score 1):

The request to `/api/somewhere` is throwing an error. Your `catchError` causes the result of `statusChangeError(error)` to be emitted from the `mergeMap`ped observable. Since the subsequent filter operator ignores the value that was emitted, it doesn't care if the value is an error. Thus if your filter predicate passes, the second `mergeMap` receives an event.

I would advise against using `filter` and `map` the way you are now, especially `filter`. Your mapping function ignores the emitted value and seems to return `undefined` every time. If you want to trigger a side effect when a value is emitted, use the `tap` operator.

Similarly, your filter predicate ignores the emitted value and instead checks some external state. Constructs like this will make your program harder to reason about. The more "pure" you can make the observables (e.g. emitting immutable values), the more testable and reasonable your code will be.

Answer (score 1):

I will post that answer it may be not exact answer to the question. But it is an answer for question in the title and I want to share my solution. You can use `fromPromise` and use ordinary promises like that:

```
export const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_USER),
    mergeMap(() =>
      fromPromise(
        fetchUser()
          .then(userResponse => 
              fetchMoreInfo()
              .then(moreInfoResponse => [userResponse, moreInfoResponse]
            ),
        ),
      ).pipe(
        map(([userResponse, moreInfoResponse]) =>
          fetchUserFullfilledAction(userResponse.data, moreInfoResponse.data),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Where `fetchUser` and `fetchMoreInfo` return ordinary promises (for example from `axios()`).
You may use `Promise.all()` if you don't care about the order. And you may rewrite fetch function using `async` `await`

With that solution you loose control over different error handling but if it is unnecessary for you that solution may be the easiest and most simple one.